# PyQt4 on Snow Leopard in 64 bit

Tags: qt4, osx-snow-leopard, pyqt4, x86-64

I just compiled the latest preview of Qt4.6 on Snow Leopard in 64 bit without any major issues.

http://qt.nokia.com/developer/qt-4.6-technology-preview#download-the-qt-4-1

Now, I am trying to do the same for PyQt4.6 with the latest snapshot from the River Bank website. However, the compiler exits with the following issue:

```
g++ -c -pipe -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O2 -Wall -W -DNDEBUG -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I/Users/drufat/Downloads/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.6-snapshot-20090914/qpy/QtCore -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/mkspecs/default -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/include -F/Users/drufat/Downloads/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.6-snapshot-20090914/qpy/QtCore -F/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib -o sipQtCoreQResource.o sipQtCoreQResource.cpp
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h: In copy constructor ‘QResource::QResource(const QResource&)’:
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h:180: error: ‘QScopedPointer<T, Cleanup>::QScopedPointer(const QScopedPointer<T, Cleanup>&) [with T = QResourcePrivate, Cleanup = QScopedPointerDeleter<QResourcePrivate>]’ is private
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qresource.h:59: error: within this context
sipQtCoreQResource.cpp: In constructor ‘sipQResource::sipQResource(const QResource&)’:
sipQtCoreQResource.cpp:78: note: synthesized method ‘QResource::QResource(const QResource&)’ first required here 
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h: In static member function ‘static void QScopedPointerDeleter<T>::cleanup(T*) [with T = QResourcePrivate]’:
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h:100:   instantiated from ‘QScopedPointer<T, Cleanup>::~QScopedPointer() [with T = QResourcePrivate, Cleanup = QScopedPointerDeleter<QResourcePrivate>]’
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qresource.h:59:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h:59: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘QResourcePrivate’ 
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h:59: error: creating array with negative size (‘-0x00000000000000001’)
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h:60: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘QResourcePrivate’ 
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h:60: error: creating array with negative size (‘-0x00000000000000001’)
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h:62: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator:
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h:54: warning: ‘pointer’ has incomplete type
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qresource.h:56: warning: forward declaration of ‘struct QResourcePrivate’
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h:62: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined.
```

Is this an error with PyQt4 trying to access a private member of a Qt4 class? Has anybody compiled PyQt4 on Snow Leopard successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got PyQt 4.6.2 working with the 64bit Python 2.6.1. I posted the instructions here: http://mpastell.com/2009/11/24/pyqt-4-6-2-with-snow-leopard/

Comment: Thanks. I already installed it through macports. 
`port install py26-pyqt4`

Answer (score 2):

In the changelogs I see Phil (PyQt's maintainer) [has issued fixes](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Downloads/PyQt4/ChangeLog-4.6-snapshot-20090914) yesterday in the development snapshots specifically for Snow Leopard:

> 2009/09/14 12:12:49  phil Further
>   fixes for Snow Leopard on 64 bit
>   systems. Added
>   QObject.pyqtConfigure().

Are you using yesterday's build of PyQt?

[This thread on the mailinglist](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2009-September/thread.html#24247) is also particulary interesting.

The PyQt compile troubles seems to be caused by Snow Leopards default 64bit compiles and the 64/32 bit mixed version of Python it ships with.

If things continue to go wrong, i would submit your problems to this mailinglist (so they can get fixed - hopefully) and try to (temporarily) rebuild Qt and PyQt (and possibly python) in a 32-bit fashion (with the -m32 compiler flag) if you need it working now.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the development snapshot from a few hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use PyQt from the homebrew project: straightforward build, managed dependencies.

Run fine on my MBP Unibody, all 64-bit.